# Конструктор файловых потоков

Tags: c++

Как известно, у файловых потоков нет конструктора, которых бы принимал аргументом объект `string`. Кто знает, почему так? Так сложилось исторически или в этом есть какой-то смысл?

Comment: Это Вы о чём?

Comment: О причинах

Comment: "у файловых потоков нет конструктора, которых бы принимал аргументом объект string"--это об чём? На пальцах объяснить можно?

Comment: string name ("name");

ofstream fs (name); - в С++03 будет ошибка

Comment: Понял. Не знаю.

Comment: Точно-точно. Однако в С++11, как тут узнал, будет работать. Там есть конструктор, определенный для string.

Comment: Ну файловый поток - это как бы не объект.

Comment: @asen, здрасьте, приехали. Есть файловые потоки Си, которые реализованы как структуры, а есть С++, которые самые настоящие объекты, с наследованием, конструкторами и прочими прелестями ООП.

Comment: @mikillskegg, тогда я вас просто не правильно понял. Следуя из вышеприведенного примера, понял, что вы пытаетесь создать файловый поток, в качестве параметра передаете объект string, где, собственно, и находится имя файла, так?

Answer (score 1):

Можно, наверное, сказать, что, мол, `iostreams` - самая старая часть стандартной библиотеки и именно поэтому там все на `const char*`, но это какое-то плохое объяснение.

Мне кажется, что про этот конструктор просто забыли в стандарте `C++03` и добавили уже в `C++11` для удобства, без каких-либо особенных причин. Собственно, это и понятно, поскольку перейти от одного конструктора к другому можно путем вызова `c_str()` или оборачивания `const char*` в `std::string`.

*В новом стандарте по этому поводу даже точно написано, что:*

> эффект от `stream(string)` равнозначен эффекту от `stream(string.c_str())`

---

Кстати говоря, в `C++11`, например, [забыли `std::make_unique`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7038357/make-unique-and-perfect-forwarding) (который `boost::make_shared`).

Comment: @Angry Bird

http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/58_426

:)

Comment: Никогда не встречал "наверно" как вводное слово, считал его уместным только как наречие, т.е. без выделения запятыми. Наверно = уверен, что так. Наверное = вероятно.